# Reasonably reliable UDP broadcast library/protocol?

Tags: udp, broadcast

I'm trying to create a shared bus over a wireless broadcast channel between multiple ad-hoc nodes.  Each node can transmit at any time, and all nodes need to be able to hear each other.  This sounds like a job for multicast, specifically [OpenPGM](http://code.google.com/p/openpgm/) (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991659/reliable-udp-broadcast-libraries) for what someone else was asking), except that what I've read about OpenPGM is that it can't handle multiple broadcasters to the same multicast address (apparently, NACKs get lost, but I'm not an expert, if anyone wants to correct me, please feel free!).  Since OpenPGM may not work, I've decided to think long and hard about my minimum requirements for a library.  Here they are:

- Must work over UDP.
- Needs to work on messages; want to be able to hand the library a message at a time, and receive back a message at a time.
- Only needs to reach the nearest neighbors!
- Needs to work on broadcast, so that many neighbors are updated at the same time.
- Needs to support multiple neighbors broadcasting at the same time, without any coordination between them.
- Needs to automatically reassemble messages from corresponding packets, and break messages up into packets.
- Only needs to be reasonably reliable; this means all of the following:

  - Messages can be lost because some packets simply don't make it through.
  - Messages may be assumed to have made it through because NACKs don't come back.
  - Any other reason you can think of.

The last set of points is important; a message can be lost, and I don't care.  That is where 'reasonably reliable' comes in; I don't want the library to hand me messages that are incomplete, I'd rather that they get dropped after some reasonable timeout period.  I also don't care if it can't guarantee delivery of any message; I can build stronger reliability guarantees on top if I need to.  Basically, it just needs to ensure that if I get a message, then it is complete.  It doesn't have to guarantee anything else.

So, is there anything similar to this?  Or should I write my own?

**EDIT**: Just to clarify, my messages are likely to be larger than a single UDP packet can handle.  If this weren't the case, I'd go for straight UDP broadcast, and put in some kind of number scheme that would let me know if I'd received a packet or not.  That is why I'm looking for a library that can handle it for me.

Also note that my nodes are themselves unreliable; they lose connectivity, and are restarted periodically.  This happens fairly rarely, but it will happen.  If a library gets hung up because a peer died, then I can't use it.

Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: How about bare bones UDP? You get best effort transport, which should fulfill your reasonable reliability requirements. And the built-in checksums should ensure completeness of the messages you receive. Are your messages sufficiently small to fit into one UDP packet?

Comment: Are all nodes on the same IP network?  You could just send UDP packets to the broadcast address.  Simple.

Comment: PGM doesn't support multiple senders on the same host sending to the same session.  It's a network protocol, not an IPC transport.

Comment: My messages can be larger, certainly larger than what can fit into a single UDP packet.  Otherwise, that is EXACTLY what I'd do! They are all on the same IP network, and the broadcast address is a good choice, except that the messages may be larger than a single UDP packet can hold.  That means some reassembly is required (hence the library).  @Steve-o Each host has exactly one sender that acts as a server to host-local processes.  All processes on a host use ZeroMQ IPC DEALER<->ROUTER sockets to ask the server to communicate over the air on their behalf.